# How to unit-test Page Objects in a Selenium framework with PowerMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, powermock

I'm working an automation framework built on Selenium 2 and based on the Page Object design pattern. I am at the point where I want to start thinking about writing test suites for my code. Due to various reasons, some of them having to do with efficiency and others having to do with my lack of ownership and control over the test environment where the web application this framework is supposed to test is installed, I wanted to avoid having to start a browser and use the SUT to verify my framework code. So, I thought that Mock objects would be decent alternative.

The problem is that I cannot really wrap my head around the idea of mock objects and I really couldn't find a decent concrete example on the internet that illustrated how this would actually work. I did find one link that appeared to be promising, but the examples were really just way too abstract to actually be useful to me.

http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/testingcodetdd.php

So, I thought I would post my simple LoginPage page object and ask for a simple example for a unit test or two for this page object using PowerMock. Here is the source code for my LoginPage object:

```
public final class LoginPage extends Page<LoginPage> {

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "username")
    private WebElement usernameBox;

    @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "password")
    private WebElement passwordBox;

    public LoginPage(final WebDriver driver) {
        this(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl(), DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    public LoginPage(final WebDriver driver, final String url) {
        super(driver, url, DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS);
    }

    public LoginPage(final WebDriver driver, final String url, final int   
        timeoutInSeconds) {
        super(driver, url, timeoutInSeconds);
    }

    public final void enterUsername(final String username) {
        usernameBox.clear();
        usernameBox.sendKeys(username);
    }

    public final void enterPassword(final String password) {
        passwordBox.clear();
        passwordBox.sendKeys(password);
    }

    public final void clickLoginButton() {
        loginButton.click();
    }

    public final HomePage loginWithGoodCredentials(final User user) {
        return login(user, HomePage.class);
}

    public final LoginPage loginWithBadCredentials(final User user) {
        return login(user, LoginPage.class);
    }

    private <T extends Page<T>> T login(final User user, final Class<T> 
        expectedPage) {

        user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getType(), expectedPage);
        enterUsername(user.getUsername());
        enterPassword(user.getPassword());
        loginButton.click();

        return Page.constructPage(getDriver(), getTimeoutInSeconds(), 
            expectedPage);
    }

}
```

I understand that mocking WebDriver and WebElement is easy because they are interfaces, according to the link I posted above. But the document I referenced doesn't make it very clear to a total newbie to Mock objects and Mocking frameworks how exactly, I use that to write a unit test for my page object. Let's take the public login methods, for example. What does a unit test for those look like exactly? I would merely need to verify that logging in with returns a page object of the expected type. Or for example, the methods which enter text into the username and password boxes... I would perhaps want to have a test that verifies that any existing text is erased before a username and password are entered. Since I wouldn't have a real browser with the real application login page loaded, I'm not exactly sure how PowerMock would instantiate and initialize all my web elements in order to do a test on the page object's publicly exposed services.

Comment: What aspects of your code do you want to test? What value does it bring you to unit test web driver code (which is unit tested in the library)?  Could you post a UI/acceptance test that actually uses this object? It sounds like you just need a verification in your actual test that the username and password field is cleared or what not.

Also you may consider migrating this question to [sqa.stackexchange](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/) which is more theoretical QA oriented.

Comment: I am thinking of deleting this question. I have decided not to use PowerMock, but to use JMockit which has very very good documentation. The other alternative is to edit the question to ask about JMockit and post my own answer. At the moment, my project priorities have shifted somewhat and the unit testing piece is pushed off for a few weeks, so I can't take action on this question for the time being because I have to focus on other things at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe http://popperfw.org is interesting for you. It is a much more flexible implementation of the page object pattern than the default implementation from selenium and it comes with direct support for "unit" testing your created PageObjects => it tests if your PageObjects match on your testet pages

http://popperfw.org/unitTest.html

Comment: This project has not been in active development in 3 years, yet the idea behind it looks good. Do you know of alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Tests are not the appropriate place for Mock objects.  Mock objects are used when UnitTesting classes which have dependencies.  You mock the dependencies so you can focus on testing the single class.

Selenium is used for browser based testing of a web page/application.  By the very nature of this being a web page indicates that there is some sort of server running and a running browser (automated in the case of Selenium).  This is, by definition, an integration test since you're testing the final "integrated" product.  If there's a problem, it might be within ClassA or perhaps the web server configuration.  Integration testing is the place to find out where that stuff breaks (this is often put in place to reduce the load on a QA team for regression tests since Unit Tests test functionality of classes and Integration Tests test the functionality of the system as a whole (or perhaps in smaller integrated parts).

With all that said, it sounds like you're mixing the two up. From your posted code, I'd say you're doing Integration Testing and you should just forget about Mock objects for now.

Comment: I'm trying to test the page objects themselves in isolation from the web pages they represent. The link I posted in my question has a basic example of unit tests for page objects using a different framework, Mockito, than the one I wanted to use when I posted my question. I have decided to use JMockit instead of Powermock because it's simpler and has much better documentation. I will eventually either delete this question or edit it to ask about JMockit and post my own answer once I understand JMockit. I'm not the first to ask about how to unit test Page Objects.

Comment: goodness, a test of the test?  That's where I draw the line, heh.  As for your question, I've used Mockito pretty extensively.  You can use Mockito to mock any non-final method/class.  Unfortunately, with your page design, you use a lot of final statements.  I would recommend removing those statements so Mockito can do it's job (it will subclass your Page if you don't have an appropriate Interface to implement its mock with)

Comment: It's not a 'test of a test'. It's a test of a class I developed in an automation framework. The object supports testing, but it is itself not a test.

Comment: I support Selena's last comment. It would be nice to get a better answer to this question.